# Web API Odata not returning correct metadata

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid, odata

I'm using OData v4 with Web API to communicate with my AngularJS web application.

More specifically I'm trying to display my data using Kendo UI Grid.

My problem is, that my Web API does not return the correct metadata, resulting in Kendos datasource not being able to display the data.

I'm doing paging, and to do that I need the "count" property in my response for Kendo UI Grid datasource to be able work properly.

The response I'm expecting the Web API should look something like this:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Toc403940644

However, the result I'm seeing in the response is:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:1983/odata/$metadata#TestReports","value":[
    {
      "Id":1,"Name":"Test Testesen","Purpose":"Kendo UI Grid Test","Type":"Rumraket","ReportedDate":"2015-02-04T10:03:59.4173323+01:00"
    },{
      "Id":2,"Name":"Gunner Testesen","Purpose":"OData Web API Test","Type":"Sutsko","ReportedDate":"2015-02-04T10:03:59.4173323+01:00"
    },{
      "Id":3,"Name":"Bertram Didriksen","Purpose":"Server Paging Test","Type":"Flyver","ReportedDate":"2015-02-04T10:03:59.4173323+01:00"
    },{
      "Id":4,"Name":"Oluf Petersen","Purpose":"Test","Type":"B\u00e5d","ReportedDate":"2015-02-04T10:03:59.4173323+01:00"
    },{
      "Id":5,"Name":"Alfred Butler","Purpose":"Opvartning","Type":"Batmobil","ReportedDate":"2015-02-04T10:03:59.4173323+01:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

My code for retrieving the data is:

```
$scope.pendingReports = {
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            beforeSend: function (req) {
                                req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=fullmetadata');
                            },
                            url: "/odata/TestReports",
                            dataType: "odata"                                    
                        },
                        parameterMap: function (options, type) {                            
                            var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);

                            console.log(paramMap);

                            delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter
                            delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter

                            console.log(paramMap);

                            return paramMap;
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: function (data) {
                            return data; // <-- The result is just the data, it doesn't need to be unpacked.
                        },
                        total: function (data) {
                            return data.length; // <-- The total items count is the data length, there is no .Count to unpack.

                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 5,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true
                },
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                dataBound: function () {
                    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "Name",
                        title: "Navn"
                    }, {
                        field: "ReportedDate",
                        title: "Indberetet den"
                    }, {
                        field: "Purpose",
                        title: "Formål"
                    }, {
                        field: "Type",
                        title: "Type"
                    }, {
                        field: "options",
                        title: "Muligheder"
                    }
                ]
            };
```

My WebApiConfig class is corrently like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Formatters.InsertRange(0, ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create());

            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "odata",
                routePrefix: "odata",
                model: GetModel()
                );
        }

        public static Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel GetModel()
        {
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

            builder.EntitySet<TestReport>("TestReports");

            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I get the Web API to return the correct metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Kendo UI Grid is not supporting OData v4.

The fix was to modify the parameterMap of the Kendo datasource, and tell it to use $count instead of $inlinecount.

Besides that I had to tell the schema to read "@odata.count" as the "total" value.

After I edited the before posted code to the ode below, I got the correct data in my response:

```
$scope.pendingReports = {
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            beforeSend: function (req) {
                                req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=fullmetadata');
                            },
                            url: "/odata/TestReports",
                            dataType: "json"                                    
                        },
                        parameterMap: function (options, type) {                            
                            var d = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);

                            delete d.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter                                                        

                            d.$count = true;

                            return d;
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: function (data) {
                            return data.value; // <-- The result is just the data, it doesn't need to be unpacked.
                        },
                        total: function (data) {
                            return data['@odata.count']; // <-- The total items count is the data length, there is no .Count to unpack.
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 5,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true
                },
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                dataBound: function () {
                    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "Name",
                        title: "Navn"
                    }, {
                        field: "ReportedDate",
                        title: "Indberetet den"
                    }, {
                        field: "Purpose",
                        title: "Formål"
                    }, {
                        field: "Type",
                        title: "Type"
                    }, {
                        field: "options",
                        title: "Muligheder"
                    }
                ]
            };
```